# Как смонтировать в /var, при загрузке в LiveUSB?

Tags: linux, live-usb

Предположим, есть установщик с дебианом.
Там есть только пункт меню с возможностью загрузке в лайв или непосредственно установкой, мне нужно загрузить лайв, но таким образом, чтобы директория ***/var*** была не в памяти, а на физическом диске.
Как это выполнить возможно?

И в том случае, если у меня уже рабочая система, и я хочу чтобы директория, например, ***/var*** была на другом диске, но файлы хочу, чтобы остались - единственный вариант - скопировать директорию на новый диск и его смонтировать в ***/var***?

Answer (score 1):

Для live дебинана нужно распаковать squashfs и добавить скрипт в `/lib/live/boot/`.

Но чтоб не копировать содержимое /var и не мучить rootfs лучше разобраться оверлеем. Создай раздел с меткой "persistence" ext4. Создай файл persistence.conf на загрузочном диске с содержимым

```
/ union
```

Тогда всё будет записываться в этот раздел, в том числе и var.

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLive/LiveUsbPersistence

подробнее https://manpages.debian.org/testing/live-boot-doc/persistence.conf.5.en.html